# Figure caption animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, animate.css

I have this script

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.profilecaption').hide();
    
           $('.profileimg').hover(
           function() {
             $(this).find('figcaption').show();
             $(this).find('figcaption').addClass('animated zoomInUp');
          },
           function() {
            $(this).find('figcaption').addClass('animated zoomOutLeft');
              $(this).find('figcaption').hide();
          });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  
  
<figure class="profileimg d-inline-block">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1">
                    <figcaption class="profilecaption"><p>1</p></figcaption>
                </figure>
                
                <figure class="profileimg d-inline-block">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2">
                    <figcaption class="profilecaption"><p>2</p></figcaption>
                </figure>
```

So, If you see my jquery above, i want to `show` and `hide` the `figcaption`. Show and hide is simple, but now i want to use `animate.css` inside `hover event`.

From my script, the working part only in `ZoomOutLeft`, so i can't see the `zoomInUp` animation. so how can i fix this ? thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

[Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) takes care of hiding/showing elements on its own. When you are using jQuery's show/hide, it conflicts with Animate.css's style rules (because jQuery show/hide add their own css rules which have higher priority than animate.css's style rules).

In the updated snippet below, I have only removed the jQuery show/hide lines.

Also, once you have added a class e.g. `zoomInUp`, then you need to remove it as well so that when user hovers on it again, the class gets added again and you can see the animation again. Hope, it makes sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //$('.profilecaption').hide();
    
           $('.profileimg').hover(
           function() {
             //$(this).find('figcaption').show();
             $(this).find('figcaption').removeClass("zoomOutLeft").delay(500).addClass('animated zoomInUp');
          },
           function() {
            $(this).find('figcaption').removeClass("zoomInUp").addClass('animated zoomOutLeft');
              //$(this).find('figcaption').hide();
          });
 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ display: none !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  
  
<figure class="profileimg d-inline-block">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1">
                    <figcaption class="profilecaption"><p>1</p></figcaption>
                </figure>
                
                <figure class="profileimg d-inline-block">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2">
                    <figcaption class="profilecaption"><p>2</p></figcaption>
                </figure>
```